# Deserializing JSON to a property with type "object"

Tags: c#, json, object, deserialization

Well, I'm trying to serialize and save an object to JSON format and then deserialize the same object in C#. The object class is as follows:

```
public class NodeModel
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public int ParentNumber { get; set; }
    public GeometryParams Geometry { get; set; }
    public object Props { get;  set; }
}
```

I cannot use concrete classes instead of the object for the type of Props since the type is different among different objects. When I Serialize the object, I use a derived type to fill Props property. The result is well-structured in the JSON file. But when I deserialize it, it returns null for Props property while other properties are deserialized successfully.

Comment: If you dont know what the type is, what do you expect to do with it?

Comment: you could use a custom converter and load everything manually, but there would need to be some way of detecting what type had been serialized to json by the properties names.

Comment: *When I Serialize the object* - what serializer are you using?  Can you please share a [mcve] showing how you serialize and deserialize your `NodeModel`?

Comment: You could change the type of `Props` to `JObject`

Comment: It worked using `JObject`. thanks @MartinStaufcik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Martin https://stackoverflow.com/users/1882699/martin-staufcik Changing the type of `Props` to `JObject` helped me get the value of `Props`.

Answer (score 2):

The json deserialiser cannot establish what type to deserialise to `Props` to. When you serialise it knows the type so it serialises as expected.

If you make `NodeModel` generic:

```
public class NodeModel<T>
{
   (...)
   public T Props { get;  set; }
}
```

you could then help the desrialiser by telling it what type to use.

```
serialiser.DeserialiseObject<NodeModel<SomeType>>(json);
```

---

## Impossibility of the task with `object`

Let's imagine that that the desrialiser has the power to scan all the possible classes. Even then, it won't be able to make the right decision in many cases.

Consider the following scenario.

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string X { get; set; }
}

public class NodeModel
{
    public object Props { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var o = new NodeModel { Props = new B() { Name = "I'm B", Color = "Blue", X = null}};

  var json = serialiser.Serialise(o);

  // Json would be something like 
  // {
  //  "Props": {
  //    "Name": "I\u0027m B",
  //    "Color": "Blue",
  //  }
  // }

  //(...)

  var o2 = serialiser.Deserialise(o); 
  
  // How can the serialiser decide what to deserialise Props to?
  // Is it A or is it B?

}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a greater model to deserialize consisting of many `NodeModel`s and other super models.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSONConvert?

Unless I misunderstood the question completely you want the type used in the class set to the property "Prop" in this scenario you receive the type of class added. Otherwise I am misunderstanding the question in it's entirety.

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string A = "";
    }
    public class NodeModel
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public int ParentNumber { get; set; }
        public GeometryParams Geometry { get; set; }
        public object Props { get; set; }
    }
    public class GeometryParams
    {
        public string PropTest { get; set; }
    }

        public void TestMethod()
    {

        var nodeModel = new NodeModel()
        {
            X = 3.5,
            Y = 4.2,
            ParentNumber = 1,
            Geometry = new GeometryParams { PropTest = "value" },
            Props = new TestClass()
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nodeModel, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,  });

        //json result
        //{ 
            //"$type":"WebApplication2.Controllers.ValuesController+NodeModel, WebApplication2",
            //"X":3.5,
            //"Y":4.2,
            //"ParentNumber":1,
            //"Geometry":{ 
                //"$type":"WebApplication2.Controllers.ValuesController+GeometryParams, WebApplication2",
                //"PropTest":"value"},
            //"Props":{ 
                //"$type":"WebApplication2.Controllers.ValuesController+TestClass, WebApplication2",
                //"A":""} 
        //}
        var nodeModel2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NodeModel>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects });
     }
```

Comment: it still doesn't know what type Props is

Comment: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nodeModel, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects })

sets the type of object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Although using `JObject` is a option, I instead suggest that you try passing the following setting arugment for serialization and deserailzation:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects };
```

That provides a specific type back on deserialization, which is a better option in my view.